# How to use Table tests on scala?

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

I'm trying to write a test with "N test cases" instead of a single test for every test case, I've found on google the `Table` class but when I try to add them to my test the class `Table` does not work, it keeps giving me the error:

> Cannot resolve overloaded method 'Table'

The test:

```
import org.scalatest.prop.TableDrivenPropertyChecks

class PublishEventServiceSpec extends AsyncWordSpec
    with FixtureSupport
    with Matchers
    with AsyncMockFactory
    with TableDrivenPropertyChecks {


    "#my test cases" should {
        "test cases" in {
            val cases = Table(1, 2)
            forAll (cases) { c => assert(c != 0) }
        }
    }
}
```

The method `forAll` also gives me the same error "Cannot resolve overloaded method 'forAll'", how can I use the `Table` and `forAll` on my tests?

scalatest version: 3.0.8

scala version: 2.11.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. The issue here is that Table takes a name first, of type `String`, and then you can add rows. This is the apply method you are trying to use:

```
def apply[A](heading : _root_.scala.Predef.String, rows : A*) : org.scalatest.prop.TableFor1[A] = { /* compiled code */ }
```

When defining:

```
val cases = Table(1, 2)
```

`1` will not be converted to `String`. In order to solve it, you need to add a name, for example:

```
val cases = Table("name", 1,2)
```

And the rest should be the same.

Comment: that works, but now my "c" parameter is giving `Cannot resolve symbol c`, did I write something wrong?

Comment: Not that I can see. Please note that in your example you are missing a `}`.

Comment: that's a typo :))